# C# Dictionary<string, object> param jarray value extraction query

Tags: c#

I am making an api server

I am trying to extract the desired vlaue value from the data in jarray from the request text.

The full text of my request is this

```
{
  "Name": "",
  "Tel": "",
  "array": [
    {
      "GroupID": "0001",
      "CodeID": "01",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "0001",
      "CodeID": "02",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "0001",
      "CodeID": "03",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "0001",
      "CodeID": "04",
      "Value": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to put only the value in array in object[] in the full text of the request

I want to put only the data I want in object[] using foreach

```
var arr = param.Values.Where(d => d.GetType() == typeof(object[])).Single() as Object[];
var codes = arr.OfType<Code>().Select(d => d.Value).ToArray();

internal class Code
{
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string CodeId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote the code with these codes but I get the error

The problem I think is that the value of the array in the full text of the request is

It seems to be an error because it is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.

How should I do the transformation in the code I added?

Comment: What does that mean `How can I enter only the data I want by going through the for statement?`

Comment: I want to put only the data I want in string[] using foreach

Comment: can you give us an example output

Comment: @codeman - sorry, fail to understand what you mean

Comment: Why don't you just deserialize the JSON into a class that contains your `Name` and `Tel` properties and a collection named `array` that is a `List<T>`  where T is a class with the three properties (`GroupID`, `CodeID`, and `Value`)

Comment: I added more code to the question, can you check it?

Comment: Why are your fumbling with the request text instead of letting the framework do the work? [Minimal API Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I am trying to extract the desired data and compare it with the response data to put only the desired data in the LIST.

Answer (score 0):

A easy solution is to deserialize in raw DTO and then transform to desired structure :

```cs
class Request
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
    public Code[] array { get; set; }
}

class Code
{
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string CodeId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(File.ReadAllText("request.json"));
        string[] values = request.array.Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
    }
}
```